# Moving title above the colorbar in Seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn, colorbar

I have made a heatmap in Seaborn, and I have a corresponding horizontal colorbar. I've added a title to the colorbar, however, the title appears below the colorbar when I actually want it above. Is there some why I can change this? And is it possible to change the font size of the title and the size of the labels on the colorbar?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,12))
graph = sns.heatmap(df_pivot, cmap="Blues", linecolor="white", linewidths=0.1, 
            cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal", "shrink":0.40, "aspect":40, "label": "Number of accidents"})


ax.set_title("Number of traffic accidents per day & hour combination", 
fontsize=30, fontweight="bold")

from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = 70 # Space between the title and graph

locs, labels = plt.yticks() # Rotating row labels
plt.setp(labels, rotation=0) # Rotating row labels

ax.xaxis.tick_top() # x axis on top
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')

graph.tick_params(axis='both',labelsize=15) # Tick label size
graph
```

This is what it looks like so far. I want the "Number of accidents" title to be ABOVE the colorbar, but BELOW the heatmap. and I want the colorbar to be as wide as the heatmap.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Plot your colorbar in separately plot like in this example. For more info read the comments:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

# set height ratios of heatmap and coresponding colorbar
# hspace shows space between plots
# adjust hspace to put your title of colorbar correctly
grid_kws = {"height_ratios": (.9, .05), "hspace": .15}
f, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(2, gridspec_kw=grid_kws, figsize=(30,12))
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, ax=ax,
    cbar_ax=cbar_ax,
    cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal","label": "Number of accidents"})

# set title and set font of title
ax.set_title("Number of traffic accidents per day & hour combination", 
fontsize=30, fontweight="bold")

# set font size of colorbar labels
cbar_ax.tick_params(labelsize=25) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I see what you have done here, but I don't want to move the "Number of traffic accidents per day & hour combination" title, that one is supposed to be above the heatmap. What I want is for the "Number of accidents" title to be above the colorbar, aka in the same position where the "Number of traffic accidents per day & hour combination" is in the picture above.

Comment: make title for axes `ax` not `cbar_ax`.

Comment: But this is back to square 1 - exactly how I had it initially. I want the "Number of accidents" title to be ABOVE the colorbar, and the ylabels (days of the week) to be horizontal...